# How to read global variable from WP-Config.php in JS file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have defined URL in wp-config file.

```
DEFINE('URL', 'google.com');
```

Now i want to access this URL from my JS theme file:

```
<script> alert(URL); </script>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use localize in **functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , function(){ 
  wp_localize_script('jquery', 'config_var', URL );
});
```

and in js file => config_var will equal the config variable value

Comment: Definitely way better than use JS in your PHP files and use `echo` :-D

Comment: Amazing solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a bit of your JS in your `PHP` file (i.e. use script tags to accomplish this). Then do the following:

1. Place the script in your php file
2. `<script> alert(<?php echo URL ?>); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

you can read the php variable inside th js using echo. use like this

```
var url='<?php echo _URL; ?>';
 alert(url);
```

Comment: It's not working :/ All i get is alert with:
`<?php echo _URL; ?>`